# create role ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, roles

I try to create new role:

```
create role newRole;
```

I get the ERROR:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

I check session_privs:

```
select * from session_privs;

PRIVILEGE
----------------------------------------
CREATE SESSION
CREATE ROLE
```

I don't know why I can't create the role. Anyone had this problem?

Comment: May be the user doesn't have quota/privileges on a tablespace, where you create the role (a default tablespace, or a tablespace you'd set as default for this particular user)

Comment: @AlexLarionov the ROLE is *not created in a tablespace* but in the *data dictionary*. the only [prerequisite](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-ROLE.html#GUID-B2252DC5-5AE7-49B7-9048-98062993E450) is `You must have the CREATE ROLE system privilege`

Answer (score 1):

This *can not* be reproduced in 11.2 XE. Here a simple validation

- first the test user is created with the two privileges
- that a connect with this user is done and the ROLE is created without problems

.

```
d:\>sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Di Mai 5 17:20:57 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create user prd identified by vod;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to prd;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create role to prd;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect prd/vod
Connected.
SQL> select privilege from session_privs;

PRIVILEGE
----------------------------------------
CREATE SESSION
CREATE ROLE

SQL> create role newRole;

Role created.
```

So most probably some trivial explanation is behind. You are connected with other user / in other database as you expect ...